# C - Processes in linux handle with any signal

Tags: c, linux, process, signals

I'm writing code that have process who have to handle with any signal i gave him. I read that i should do something like that

```
void signalHandler(int sig_num)
{
    // some stuff
}

//My process
int i;
for (i = 1; i <= 64; i++)
     signal(i, signalHandler);
```

Is this correct solution ??

Comment: It's hard to know if a solution is correct without knowing what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: The direct answer to this direct question is "no".

Comment: My process have to handle with any signal that i send. So if i sent for example SIGINT or one of others it should go to function for this signal. I don't want to write signal(..., signalHandler) for all signals so i want to know how to make it universal.

Comment: Does your code know what signals it's handling or not?

Comment: My program can get one of 64 signals and for all of them i want have one function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although @Dylan's solution seems  good and it is but it poses the a common problem and that is compatibility issue with `signal` function. It is hence recommended that you use `sigaction` always. Here is an example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

static void handler(int signo){
   write(stdout, &signo, sizeof(int));
}

int main() {
   struct sigaction sa;
   sa.sa_handler = handler;
   int i;
   for (i = 1; i <= 64; i++) {
        sigaction(i, &sa, NULL);
   }
   while(1);
  return 0;
}
```

1. Try to avoid the use of `signal` as much as possible
2. Never use any function which are not **[Reentrant](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reentrant-function/)** or not **Async-signal-safe** functions in signal handler like `printf`

Check the list of allowed functions in signal handler from [**here**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)

> POSIX.1-2004 (also known as POSIX.1-2001 Technical Corrigendum 2)
>          requires an implementation to guarantee that the following functions
>          can be safely called inside a signal handler:

Comment: Can you say more about why we should avoid signal function ?? And whar kind of problem we can have with this function ?

Comment: `signal` function has portability issue and in few BSD systems, it needs separate unloader..Google and you will find enough info about it.

Comment: Thanks. btw it's really interesting solution :)

Comment: I found that in previous OS in signal function the signalHandler have to return int but now it can return void.

Comment: Actually the int value can be used to denote the address of the previous signal disposition. It can also be left blank.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track if you want to handle signals 1 through 64 with the same signal handler.  This test program will handle signals 1 through 64 by printing out its number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

void signalHandler(int sig_num)
{
    printf("Signal %d caught!\n", sig_num);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    //My process
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 64; i++) {
        signal(i, signalHandler);
    }

    while (1);
    return 0;
}
```

For example, when you press CTRL+C while this program is running.  The kernel sends signal 2 `SIGINT` to the program, and calls `signalHandler(2)`.  This program prints "Signal 2 caught!"

Post-Facepalm edit: this program obviously needs to be terminated with a `kill -9` command........

Comment: Can clear me how this for works because i want to uderstand why in any time it read our signal. Or for() should be in infinitive loop ??

Comment: Explaining signals is a little too in-depth for a StackOverflow comment, but check out some resources online like http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal.  Basically, `signal(i, signalHandler)` tells the kernel to call signalHandler whenever signal `i` is caught.  You call `signal(i, signalHandler)` for i=1, i=2, ... i=63, i=64.  So signals 1-64 trigger the `signalHandler` function

Comment: A table of some unix signals can be found at http://people.cs.pitt.edu/~alanjawi/cs449/code/shell/UnixSignals.htm.

Comment: I know how function signal() works but i want to uderstand why we do for() loop. For me it should be: 64 times do function signal() and then infinitive loop while(1). Or this react only when we send signal to this process ?

Comment: Having a little trouble understanding the question.  The for loop calls `signal` 64 times.  The infinite while loop makes the program loop forever.

Comment: So if i send signal to this process how he will handle with this signal ??

Comment: If you send a signal to this process, the kernel will pause, or interrupt, the main execution of your program (the infintite loop) and jump to the `signalHandler` function.  Once `signalHandler` has finished its job, it will return control to the main program (the infinite loop).

Comment: so if we don't send signal the for loop won't trigger signal function ?

Comment: The for loop triggers the signal function at the beginning of the program before any signal has been sent.  The `signal` function just sets up your program to receive a signal.  The `signalHandler` function will not be triggered if you don't send a signal.

Comment: This is what i ask from the begining. Other question can we print name of the signal not only number ?? In your code you print only number is there any way to print name of this signal ?? for example SIGALRM ??

Comment: Can i do something like that printf("%s", strsignal(sig_num)); ?? When i'm doing this it isn't work

Comment: Make sure you `#include <string.h>` to use it.  The line `printf("Signal %s caught!\n", strsignal(sig_num));` works on my machine

Comment: I'm sorry it works. But is there any way to printf "SIGINT" not "Interrupt" ??

Comment: Not without defining your own function to translate :(

Comment: Ok really thanks a lot for all help you gave me :) At last now i know what i'm doing :)